# Two signed 64bit multiplication using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, arm

I am trying to multiply two signed 64 bit long data using GCC

```
long long int A;//(A0,A1)
long long int B;//(B0,B1)
```

can you please help me on the following things

1. How to input 64bit number using scanf
2. How to printf
3. multiply the  two numbers

Comment: Items 1 and 2: read the documentation and then use `%lli`? ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. `scanf("%lld", &A);`
2. `printf("%lld", A);`
3. `A*B`

Comment: Bingo! Points in your basked!

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I am on 32 bit machine(ARM), i have tried that but doesnt work. since the registers are only 32 bit and i defined using long long int a 64 bit data then the multiplication would be larger than 64 bit.

Comment: Oh, you want a 64x64 -> 128 bit multiply? In that case, you should break the operands into 32-bit parts and use long multiplication.

Comment: ya, that is what i am trying to do. can you please give me more explanation. thanks

Comment: Suppose you're trying to multiply two 2-digit numbers in decimal to get a 4-digit number. Do long multiplication like you learned in grade school. Now, instead of base 10, do it in base 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure that `long long int` is 64-bit. You should try doing:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t A, B;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will include that, but to input, output and finally multiply?

Comment: `long long` is always *at least* 64 bits, so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this ,I am also checking and will comment my results.

```
void mulul64(uint64 u, uint64 v, uint64 *whi, uint64 *wlo)
{
uint64 u0, u1, v0, v1, k, t;
uint64 w0, w1, w2;
u1 = u >> 32; u0 = u & 0xFFFFFFFF;
v1 = v >> 32; v0 = v & 0xFFFFFFFF;
t = u0*v0;
w0 = t & 0xFFFFFFFF;
k = t >> 32;
t = u1*v0 + k;
w1 = t & 0xFFFFFFFF;
w2 = t >> 32;
t = u0*v1 + w1;
k = t >> 32;
*wlo = (t << 32) + w0;
*whi = u1*v1 + w2 + k;
return;
}
```